# Dealing with Date Ranges Crossing Periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a Date Range specified across DateFrom and DateTo fields and a TotalValue field.

Depending on the date range specified, i.e. this:

```
DECLARE @ReportStartDate datetime = '31 May 2019'
DECLARE @ReportEndDate datetime = '2 Jun 2019'
```

It would pick up the NULL values, and also the 2019-05-31-2019-06-07 row, but the TotalValue would be (48 / 7) * 2 as it is only 2 days of the range.

Expected Result.

[image]

If the below is specified:

```
DECLARE @ReportStartDate datetime = '04 Jun 2019'
DECLARE @ReportEndDate datetime = '14 Jun 2019'
```

It would pick up the NULL values, and also the 2019-05-31-2019-06-05 row, but the TotalValue would be (48 / 7) * 3  as it is only 3 days of the range.

Expected Result

[image]

Anyone know how this could be approached? I have the following query so far which solves Use Case 1, but I'm not sure how to approach Use Case 2

```
select 
    *,
    CASE WHEN DateFrom is null Then TotalValue Else (TotalValue/7) * DateDiff(dd,DateFrom,@ReportEndDate) END as CalculatedValue
from 
    #TestData
where DateFrom is null
or DateFrom >=@ReportStartDate
```

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData
(
    DateFrom date NULL,
    DateTo date NULL,
    TotalValue money
)
INSERT INTO #TestData
(
    DateFrom,
    DateTo,
    TotalValue
)
SELECT
    NULL,
    NULL,
    250
UNION ALL
SELECT
    '2019-05-31',
    '2019-06-07',
    48
UNION ALL
SELECT
    '2019-05-24',
    '2019-05-31',
    336
UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL,
    NULL,
    134 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    '2019-04-19',
    '2019-04-26',
    336

select * from #TestData

drop table #TestData
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking here. What is you problem? Also, can you please show the query you re having problems with and the expected results.

Comment: You've done a great job with the sample data, but no so much with the desired output. Please [edit] your question to include your current attempt and your desired output as formatted text data set.

Comment: Sorry guys, expected result added.

Comment: Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). A lot of it's point is also relevant to desired output.

Comment: If you don't want null's use "where blah is not null"

Comment: What dates are in range in the first example? What dates are in range in the second one?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - First one is 31/1 (2 days) and Second one is 4/5/6 (3 days)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - re the images for output, I searched and there's no easy way to convert a Excel spreadsheet to a table for Stackoverflow from what I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression, `datediff` and a couple of `iif` to get the `CalculatedValue`.

The case expression has two branches:

1. If the either of the `DateFrom` or `DateTo` columns has `null` instead of a `value`, you simply return the `TotalValue`.
2. This is where it gets interesting: If the date ranges overlap, calculate the number of days they overlap, and then divide the `TotalValue` by 7 and multiply it by the number of days.

I've added some comments to the code, hope it's clear enough:

```
DECLARE @ReportStartDate date = '2019-05-31', @ReportEndDate date = '2019-06-02'

SELECT  DateFrom, 
        DateTo, 
        TotalValue,
        CASE 
            -- dates are null
            WHEN DateFrom IS NULL OR DateTo IS NULL THEN TotalValue

            -- devide by 7 and multiply be the number of days within range
            ELSE TotalValue / 7 * DATEDIFF(DAY,
                                           -- latest of start dates
                                           IIF(DateFrom > @ReportStartDate, DateFrom, @ReportStartDate),
                                           -- earliest of end dates
                                           IIF(DateTo < @ReportEndDate, DateTo, @ReportEndDate)
                                           )
        END  As CalculatedValue
FROM #TestData
-- Get only date ranges that overlap or the date columns are null
WHERE (DateFrom IS NULL OR DateFrom < @ReportEndDate)
AND (DateTo IS NULL OR DateTo > @ReportStartDate)
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Zohar Peled. Is it possible to remove your point 2 however, as these results shouldn't show in the query as they are not in anyway within the date range

Comment: No problem, but you'll have to add a condition to the where clause to eliminate these rows. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zohar Peled - that works a treat.  Thanks for bearing with me with the question too.

Comment: Glad to help :-)